# Retrofit2: @Path parameter in OkHttp Interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

In our API we have sign based on both @Query and @Path parameters. Everyone suggests to use OkHttp Interceptor for this. Everything is fine with query params, but I don't think there is any way to get path parameter values and names. For example:

```
/api/{version}/books/{id}
/api/v1.1/books/10
```

To make a correct sign, I need Map:

```
{"id":"10", "version":"v1.1"}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following code, probably your problem will be solved.

/api/{version}/books/{id}

public type method(@Path("version") String versionValue,@Path("id") String idValue,.....)

Comment: I need this values in OkHttp Interceptor to modify all my requests (calculate and add a sign)

Comment: Read the following post, probably you will be solve your problem.                              http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/a-smart-way-to-use-retrofit/

Comment: if you get the right solution, please mark the answer as right answer.

Comment: This post is about old Retrofit 1.x.x